# How to subset and approximate a private dataset's characteristics?

Tags: dataset

Assume an Object Detection task. The private dataset has its bounding-box (bbox) characteristics, and assume only width-height measures are relevant.

Assume we know what is that width-height distribution of the private dataset.

**How is it possible to approximate this distribution based on an existing dataset, which is available?**

I though of clustering the private dataset's distribution (for, say $k=10$ clusters, $M \in R^{(k\times2)}$), then greedily picking the closest samples from the available dataset.

I'm wondering what are the available tools, because this first intuition feels way off the optimal